# Solving for Function with Given Indicated Values

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm relatively new to the world of functions and solving them with given values, so I'm completely lost here. The question is as follows: "Given the following function, find the indicated values: $f(x)$ = $x^2$ - $5x$ + $1$

How would I solve this problem? Where would I even begin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "solving" the function. I think they gave you a function:
$$f(x)=x^2-5x+1$$
and told you to find $f(7)$ or something. In that case, I will try to explain not only how to find $f(7)$, but how functions are in general (since you said you were new to functions).

First, you find $f(7)$ by plugging in $7$ to every $x$. That means that $f(7)=7^2-5(7)+1$. Then you evaluate it. $f(7)=49-35+1=15$. That means $f(7)=15$. I will talk about how this is important later.

A *function* is like a machine. $f$ is the name of the machine (it can be $g$ or $h$ or whatever you like), and $x$ is the thing you input into the machine. Our machine $f(x)=x^2-5x+1$ is saying this: "Throw some $x$ into me, and I will give you $x^2-5x+1$!" When you throw a $7$ into the machine, the machine gives you $7^2-5(7)+1$, which is $15$.

Our machine can only output one number. If it has to choose between $2$ numbers, it will not know what to do. For example, if the machine handles the equation $x^2+y^2=25$, and you throw an $x$ value of $4$ into the equation and ask it to solve for $y$, it will think:

"Okay, $4^2+y^2=25$. So $y^2=25-16=9$. $y=\pm 3$. Which one?! $3$ or $-3$?!!" $\text{*self destructs*}$

**Every function must have only one y-value for every x-value.** Our equation $x^2+y^2=25$ is *not* a function! because for an x-value of $4$, there were two possible y-values; $3$ and $-3$. If you are curious, the graph of the equation above is of a circle having a centre $(0,0)$ and radius $5$.

**Every point on the graph of a function must be in the form $(x, f(x))$.** Let's take our first example $f(x)=x^2-5x+1$. We found out that $f(7)=15$. A point on the graph of $f(x)=x^2-5x+1$ is going to be $(7, f(7))$, which is $(7,15)$. On the other hand, $(7,14)$ is **not** on the graph! because $f(7)\neq 14$.

You will learn a lot more about functions and their graphs later on, but I think that, for now, this is all you need to know.

---

OP has specified that he was given nothing else except $f(x)=x^2-5x+1$. He has to "solve for the function", so I am going to guess that he wants to find the *roots* of the function.

A **root** is/are the point(s) where the graph of the function intersects the x-axis. In other words, $f(x)=0$. This is also referred to as a *zero*, or an *x-intercept*. If you think about it, this is a system of equations with two equations and two unknowns.
$$\begin{cases} f(x)=x^2-5x+1 \\ f(x)=0 \\ \end{cases}$$
We know $f(x)=0$. Therefore $0=x^2-5x+1$. This is called *solving by substitution*. We are making the substitution $f(x)=0$. How do we solve $x^2-5x+1=0$? There is a very well known formula called the *Quadratic Formula*. It states:

> For any equation in the form $ax^2+bx+c=0$, where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are constants and $a\neq 0$, $x$ is equal to:
>   $$x=\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

We can apply this formula to our equation $x^2-5x+1=0$. We know that $a=1$, $b=-5$, and $c=1$. Therefore:
$$x=\frac{-(-5)\pm\sqrt{(-5)^2-4(1)(1)}}{2(1)}$$
$$x=\frac{5\pm\sqrt{25-4}}{2}$$
$$x=\frac{5\pm\sqrt{21}}{2}$$
So the solutions are:
$$x=\frac{5+\sqrt{21}}{2}$$
$$x=\frac{5-\sqrt{21}}{2}$$
Now we have our roots. We say that, "The roots are $\dfrac{5+\sqrt{21}}{2}$ and $\dfrac{5-\sqrt{21}}{2}$."

---

Perhaps you also want to find the *y-intercept*. This is much easier than finding the roots. The y-intercept is where the graph intersects with the y-axis. In other words, the y-intercept is where the x-coordinate is $0$. Therefore the y-intercept will have the coordinates $(0, y)$. Remember what I said about every point on a function having coordinates $(x, f(x))$? We know that $x=0$, so the y-intercept is going to be  $(0, f(0))$. We just need to find $f(0)$, which is easy.
$$f(0)=0^2-5(0)+1$$
$$f(0)=1$$
Therefore the y-intercept has coordinates $(0,1)$. We just say that, "The y-intercept is $1$."

---

If you want to know how to derive the quadratic formula, here is how I do it. We have our standard equation:
$$ax^2+bx+c=0$$
Multiply by $4a$ on both sides:
$$4a^2x^2+4abx+4ac=0$$
Subtract $4ac$ from both sides:
$$4a^2x^2+4abx=-4ac$$
There is a formula that $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$. We can then the left hand side into a expression of the form $(a+b)^2$ by adding $b^2$ to both sides.
$$4a^2x^2+4abx+b^2=b^2-4ac$$
$$(2ax)^2+2(2ax\cdot b)+(b)^2=b^2-4ac$$
$$(2ax+b)^2=b^2-4ac$$
Taking the square root of both sides:
$$2ax+b=\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}$$
$$2ax=-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}$$
$$\displaystyle \boxed{x=\dfrac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}}$$
And that is how you derive the quadratic formula.

---

I could go on and on about parabolas (the graph of any quadratic equation is a parabola; a U shape), talking about foci, directrix, etc. But I feel like you are getting bored! So I am going to stop here, because this is basically functions in a nutshell.

---

Hope I helped!

Comment: Thanks, this did help quite a bit! And lol at the self destructs part! I shall definitely refer to your answer more often -- thanks! However, they didn't give me anything. Just what I typed, no 7 or any other number so that's what had me confused.

Comment: @user1925224 Perhaps they mean to solve for the *roots*. I will explain how to do this in my edited post

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you are given a list of $x$ values.  You are supposed to fill in a table, evaluating $f(x)$ at each of those values.  Something like $$\begin {array}{c| c} x&f(x) \\\hline 0&1\\1&-3\\2&-5 \end {array}$$

Comment: That makes sense, but I'm still a bit lost here. Actual numbers in my question are 5 and +1. Do I only make the table with those numbers? How exactly did you make this table? What'd you do? As you can see, not so great with this new topic.

Comment: I plugged each $x$ value into your formula $f(x)$.  Can you confirm the right side?  Especially since I fixed the value for $f(2)?$  For example, $f(3)=3^2-5\cdot 3 +3=9-15+1=-5$.  You should check the other three to make sure you understand.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I'm still looking into the problem based on what you told me and my own notes, so thanks for the tip! I'll be sure to check back if I find I don't get it, still.